# Is there a dictionary for Woogles.IO?

Tags: scrabble

I've been getting into Scrabble recently, playing at [Woogles.IO](https://woogles.io/).  Only I don't know what are or aren't counted as words there.

I realize that, depending on playing mode, I can try placing words midgame and they won't be placed if they don't count, but that's not an ideal way to study.

**Question**: Is there a dictionary for Woogles.IO?

I didn't find the answer via [a Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=Is+there+a+dictionary+for+Woogles.IO?).

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe the dictionary is anything other than OSW?

Answer (score 2):

The two main English dictionaries you can use on Woogles as of this writing, I believe, are:

- CSW21 (World English) -- This is the Collins Scrabble Words list used pretty much everywhere except North America
- NWL20 (North American English) -- This is the [NASPA](http://scrabbleplayers.org/w/Welcome_to_NASPAWiki) Word List, used in most North American competitive endeavors

When you start a game, you have the option to choose whatever dictionary you please. When you are looking to challenge another player when they have a game requested, you should be able to see in the "Words" column what dictionary they wish to play with.

[image: Woogles lexicon dropdrown]

Answer (score 1):

As you said, it depends on the lexicon you use, either OSW (Official Scrabble Words) or CEL (Common Word Lexicon)

1. **[scrabblewordfinder](https://scrabblewordfinder.org/dictionary-checker)** finds if a word exists at the OSW.
2. For words in CEL look at the [Dictionary-sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1N-LfFbuuVA176f6pI8oTHYtpUGOy7t2i_ovsCTalq4A/edit#gid=1789069898), which is referenced in [their github](https://github.com/Fj00/CEL), which is referenced in their blog: [Woogles.io’s secret features](https://blog.woogles.io/guides/secret-features/)

Note that:

> If you want to play with an English Common Word Lexicon, you must have all lexicons enabled (go to Settings, select Preferences on the menu on the left, and click on the “Enable All Lexicons” slider).
> Now you can play a very small dictionary of only common words. This dictionary is subject to change at any time as we experiment with it.
> You can find the word list here: https://github.com/Fj00/CEL